# Is there a way to bind local IPEndPoint to FtpClient object in FluentFTP library?

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest, fluentftp

So far I have tried this

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = delegate
{
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    return new IPEndPoint(ip, 0);
};
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
```

The issue is `FtpWebRequest` class has limited functionality where as `FtpClient` is more versatile. How do I bind local `IpEndpoint` to `FtpClient` class in FluentFTP library? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be possible.

FluentFTP let's you only to choose what IP version you want to use by `InternetProtocolVersions`.